# Ansible set_fact Nested Variables in Playboook

Tags: variables, ansible, nested, set, fact

I've been working on this problem for a while and can't find a solution.

My playbook is:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    vpc_stack_name: "VPC-CF"

  tasks:
  - name: Get summary information about a stack
    amazon.aws.cloudformation_info:
      stack_name: "{{ vpc_stack_name }}"
    register: vpc_stack_facts

  - debug:
      var: "vpc_stack_facts.cloudformation['{{ vpc_stack_name }}'].stack_outputs['VPCID']"

  - set_fact:
      temp: "{{ vpc_stack_facts.cloudformation['{{ vpc_stack_name }}'].stack_outputs['VPCID'] }}"
```

I know the embedded `{{ vpc_stack_name }}` is wrong and not allowed but can't figure out how to get around it.

I haven't got the grasp of Ansible **lookups** as yet.

Thank You in advance!!

Comment: It looks ok for `debug` as your are reconstructing a var name for the `var` attribute. For yous `set_fact` you cannot nest jinja2 markers, just use the var name which holds the corresponding value => `"{{ vpc_stack_facts.cloudformation[vpc_stack_name].stack_outputs['VPCID'] }}"`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, the use of Jinja expressions `{{ vpc_stack_name }}` while inside a Jinja context is not correct. Ansible will try to evaluate any text without quotes as a variable. So you can keep the `vpc_stack_name` variable as it is: `[vpc_stack_name]`.

Example:

```yaml
  vars:
    vpc_stack_name: VPC-CF

  tasks:
  - cloudformation_info:
      stack_name: "{{ vpc_stack_name }}"
    register: vpc_stack_facts
  - set_fact:
      temp_var: "{{ vpc_stack_facts['cloudformation'][vpc_stack_name|quote]['stack_outputs']['VPC'] }}"
  - debug:
      var: temp_var
```

Note: In the above example I am using the key as `VPC` to get the VPC ID as output.

- Used `['']` notation instead of dots `.` to access dict items
- Used `|quote` filter around the variable `vpc_stack_name`

Yields:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "temp_var": "vpc-1234ab5678c90d1e"
}
```

Comment: OP's current expression for `debug: var` is totally correct (even though I would rather recommand using `msg` with below in this case) and should not fire an error. Removing the dot notation is only required to use variables or literal key name containing "special" chars (space, dash, etc...) and not required for `stack_outputs` (although you perfectly have the choice). `"{{  vpc_stack_facts.cloudformation[vpc_stack_name].stack_outputs.VPCID }}"` will work for both a `set_fact` or a `debug: msg`

Comment: Yes the issue was having Jinja expression within a Jinja context for `debug: msg` or `set_fact`.. I realized it works with dot notation as well, but having `[]` seems more consistent.

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion ;) I always favor the dot notation over the array one (less verbose) and don't care about mixing. My point was: you don't have to change it in this case and that is actually not a fix for OP's problem.

Comment: My intention *was not* to say that using `[]` or `|quote` is going to fix OP's issue. in case it sounded like that I changed the order for explaining my example.

Comment: Thank you @seshadri_c & Zeitounator  This is really appreciated!  I didn't realize I was using a combination of dot notation and []!!! I was blindly following another example to get to specific stack output!