# Ansible variable interpolation

Tags: dictionary, ansible, interpolation

Clearly I am missing something (obvious?) here :-(
Dictionary is correctly resolved as var in debug, but I can't get it into a message (msg). How do I trigger interpolation in this case correctly? (The actual usecase is not debug, but this is a most simple example I could construct).

```
---
- name: Setup based on subnet
  hosts: 
    - localhost
  vars:
    siteVars:
      10.128.0.0:
        ServerName:  "AServ"
      10.0.0.0:
        ServerName:  "BServ"
 
  tasks:
  - name: Do we get the right Network
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}"

  - name: Var works
    debug: 
      var: siteVars[ {{ 'ansible_default_ipv4.network' }} ].ServerName

  - name: Msg does not work interpolate
    debug:
       msg: "siteVars[ {{ 'ansible_default_ipv4.network' }} ].ServerName"
```

Gives:

```
TASK [Do we get the right Network] ******************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "10.0.0.0"
}

TASK [Var works] ******************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "siteVars[ ansible_default_ipv4.network ].ServerName": "BServ"
}

TASK [Msg does not work interpolate] ******************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "siteVars[ ansible_default_ipv4.network ].ServerName"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I trigger interpolation in this case correctly?

Since `siteVars` and `ServerName` are part of the data structure (variable) too, the curly braces needs to surround them also.

```
- name: Msg work interpolate too
  debug:
    msg: "{{ siteVars[ansible_default_ipv4.network].ServerName }}"
```

Resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Msg work interpolate too] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: BServ
```

Other related questions here

- [How can I use Ansible nested variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209556/)
- [Accessing nested variable variables in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501711/)
- [Ansible `set_fact` nested variables in playboook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65624245/)

**Documentation**

- Ansible FAQ: [When should I use {{ }}? How to interpolate variables or dynamic variable names?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: Note that, although a bit confusing for a beginner, the following option to `debug` works: `var: siteVars["{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}"].ServerName`

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting me on the right track. Much appreciated.